# Set dock icon name when hoverd over

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently developing a small chat app as a personal project in javafx. I've just managed changing the dock icon on mac from a folder to an image using:

```
    URL imageResource = Main.class.getResource("/ui/new-modified.jpeg");


    Image image = defaultToolkit.getImage(imageResource);
    Taskbar taskbar = Taskbar.getTaskbar();

    try {
        //set icon for mac os (and other systems which do support this method)
        taskbar.setIconImage(image);
    } catch (final UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        System.out.println("The os does not support: 'taskbar.setIconImage'");
    } catch (final SecurityException e) {
        System.out.println("There was a security exception for: 'taskbar.setIconImage'");
    }
```

Which I got from another answer here. I couldn't use the otherwise easy methods, since none of them worked for some reason. I'm now trying to change the name of the icon when I hover the mouse over it, see the picture: [image]

In other words, where it says java. I've tried using `stage.setTitle` but it won't work, it will only show text at the top of the program..

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: It doesn't look like `java.awt.Taskbar` provides an API for this. Most likely the "java" is coming from the fact that the executable running your application is named "java". I expect the name will change after you properly deploy your application (e.g., via `jpackage` with an appropriate `--name` option).

Comment: I tried via `jpackage`. This worked for me on a Mac previously.  But on OS X 13.2.1, Java/JavaFX 19, the packaging failed for me when executing the resultant app with the obscure error "<my app name> is damaged and can't be opened.  You should move it to the Trash."  Looking into this, it is [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8276150) which was resolved, then reverted.

Comment: To get around it, you need to sign the app.  Apple offer free ["Apple Developer"](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/reference/supported-capabilities-macos) certificates which you can use to [sign the application package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/jpackage/support-application-features.html#GUID-8D9F0607-91F4-4070-8823-02FCAB12238D), but jpackage only supports the paid Apple "Developer ID" certificates.  So, as far as I can tell, to get this to work, you have to both endure the packaging pain, and pay out of pocket to Apple.